# i will expected ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows. what is problem?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

```
create or replace trigger "AGE_TRIGGER4"
BEFORE
insert on CLIENT
for each row
DECLARE
age DATE;
BEGIN
select DATA into age from CLIENT where "FIO" = :new."FIO";
if SYSDATE-age > 27394 OR age is NULL Then
raise_application_error(-20001,'...');
end if;
end;
```

I will expected ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: well, what did you get as the error message then ?

Comment: if i try to add a new row, i get an error "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"

Answer (score 1):

The only statement that can raise `too_many_rows` is

```
select DATA into age from CLIENT where "FIO" = :new."FIO";
```

It means that there's more than one row in the `client` table with the same `fio` column value. If that's expected, you should handle it somehow.

- For example, you could select `max(data) into age`
- Or, you could raise an exception notifying users that they can't enter two (or more) rows with the same `fio`. Though, you'd rather let the database handle it - create a unique index on that column
- Or, include another column(s) into the `where` clause to further restrict values returned by the `select` statement